# Scala Either map Right or return Left

Tags: scala, either

Is it possible to handle `Either` in similar way to `Option`? In `Option`, I have a `getOrElse` function, in `Either` I want to return `Left` or process `Right`. I'm looking for the fastest way of doing this without any boilerplate like:

```
val myEither:Either[String, Object] = Right(new Object())
myEither match {
    case Left(leftValue) => value
    case Right(righValue) => 
        "Success"
}
```

Comment: what is value in the case Left? Did you mean leftValue?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Scala 2.12,

> [Either is right-biased, which means that Right is assumed to be the default case to operate on. If it is Left, operations like map, flatMap, ... return the Left value unchanged](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Either.html)

so you can do

```
myEither.map(_ => "Success").merge
```

if you find it more readable than `fold`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`.fold`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Either@fold[X](fa:A=>X,fb:B=>X):X):

```
scala> val r: Either[Int, String] = Right("hello")
r: Either[Int,String] = Right(hello)

scala> r.fold(_ => "got a left", _ => "Success")
res7: String = Success

scala> val l: Either[Int, String] = Left(1)
l: Either[Int,String] = Left(1)

scala> l.fold(_ => "got a left", _ => "Success")
res8: String = got a left
```

---

Edit:

Re-reading your question it's unclear to me whether you want to return the value in the `Left` or another one (defined elsewhere)
If it is the former, you can pass `identity` to `.fold`, however this might change the return type to `Any`:

```
scala> r.fold(identity, _ => "Success")
res9: Any = Success
```

Answer (score 7):

Both cchantep's and Marth's are good solutions to your immediate problem. But more broadly, it's difficult to treat Either as something fully analogous to `Option`, particularly in letting you express sequences of potentially failable computations for comprehensions. Either has a projection API (used in cchantep's solution), but it is a bit broken. (Either's projections break in for comprehensions with guards, pattern matching, or variable assignment.)

FWIW, I've written a [library](https://github.com/swaldman/leftright) to solve this problem. It augments Either with [this API](http://www.mchange.com/work/enrich-bias-either/enrich-bias-either-2015-09-19/index.html#scala.util.Either$$RightBias$). You define a "bias" for your Eithers. "Right bias" means that ordinary flow (map, get, etc) is represented by a `Right` object while `Left` objects represent some kind of problem. (Right bias is conventional, although you can also define a left bias if you prefer.) Then you can treat the `Either` like an `Option`; it offers a fully analogous API.

```
import com.mchange.leftright.BiasedEither

import BiasedEither.RightBias._

val myEither:Either[String, Object] = ...
val o = myEither.getOrElse( "Substitute" )
```

More usefully, you can now treat Either like a true scala monad, i.e. use flatMap, map, filter, and for comprehensions:

```
val myEither : Either[String, Point] = ???
val nextEither = myEither.map( _.x ) // Either[String,Int]
```

or

```
val myEither : Either[String, Point] = ???
def findGalaxyAtPoint( p : Point ) : Either[String,Galaxy] = ???

val locPopPair : Either[String, (Point, Long)] = {
  for { 
    p <- myEither    
    g <- findGalaxyAtPoint( p )
  } yield {
    (p, g.population)
  }
}
```

If all processing steps succeeded, `locPopPair` will be a `Right[Long]`. If anything went wrong, it will be the first `Left[String]` encountered.

It's slightly more complex, but a good idea to define an empty token. Let's look at a slight variation on the for comprehension above:

```
val locPopPair : Either[String, (Point, Long)] = {
  for { 
    p <- myEither    
    g <- findGalaxyAtPoint( p ) if p.x > 1000
  } yield {
    (p, g.population)
  }
}
```

What would happen if the test `p.x > 1000` failed? We'd want to return some `Left` that signifies "empty", but there is no universal appropriate value (not all `Left`'s are `Left[String]`. As of now, what would happen is the code would throw a `NoSuchElementException`. But we can specify an empty token ourselves, as below:

```
import com.mchange.leftright.BiasedEither

val RightBias = BiasedEither.RightBias.withEmptyToken[String]("EMPTY")
import RightBias._

val myEither : Either[String, Point] = ???
def findGalaxyAtPoint( p : Point ) : Either[String,Galaxy] = ???

val locPopPair : Either[String, (Point, Long)] = {
  for { 
    p <- myEither    
    g <- findGalaxyAtPoint( p ) if p.x > 1000
  } yield {
    (p, g.population)
  }
}
```

Now, if the `p.x > 1000` test fails, there will be no Exception, `locPopPair` will just be `Left("EMPTY")`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can do as follows.

```scala
def foo(myEither: Either[String, Object]) = 
  myEither.right.map(rightValue => "Success")
```

Comment: Looks like `foo` should return a `String`, not a `Either`. Aren't you missing a `.getOrElse(value)` at the end?

Comment: "either I want to return Left or process Right" is what's done by mapping the right projection. For an `Either[A, B]` the goal is to get either a `A` (provided a `B => A` for `Right`) or a `B` (provided a `A => B` for `Left`), then `.fold` is your friend.

Comment: You're right, I read the question too quickly. I just looked at the code in it and thought the question was "how do I write this more succinctly". My bad.

Answer (score -1):

In scala 2.13, you can use myEither.getOrElse

```html
   Right(12).getOrElse(17) // 12
   Left(12).getOrElse(17)  // 17
```

Comment: This does the opposite of what was requested. The OP wants to return the **Left** and replace the **Right**.